# Select the text of HTML pages

Tags: html, css, text

When I'm selecting text, just select the text and nothing else.

For example:
In this page, please press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>,
Text is selected in addition to other things!!? (Meaning that it is blue in color).

How do I select just the text?
Is there a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I your text is inside textarea, frame or some editable component then only you can select the text using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> otherwise the selection scope goes to whole page

Comment: is there a way that tags such as p, h1, ... Have similar behavior tag textaria?

Comment: <p contenteditable="true">content goes here ...</p> it will make your <p> editable such that you can select using CTRL+A. if you want diable delete,cut...etc just disable particular using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+A is is used for selecting all (the entire page). But if  you need to select only text in HTML page , my suggestion is to use your mouse (Drag your mouse for select, by pressing left mouse button). Hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It truly depends on the building of the site. Whether the content of the html text you want to copy is in swf format or html format.

A) If it is in html format then there are two possibilities:

- The site builder uses "read only" the content using javascript/jQuery. Therefore that specific text we can't copy it by using Ctrl+A. 
  However its solution is if you are using firebug, a plugin in firefox browser, you may inspect element the specific portion and copy the text portion you need to use. And it is abnormal way of using each text using this method.
- If there is nothing any check of "read only" as like 98% of the sites uses, you may copy the text by using the short cut key Ctrl+A or drag your mouse.

B) If it is SWF format, a flash based website, then you have to surf search engines for the specific task.

I hope it will carry you understanding the answer.